# \ignorespaces does not work inside \ul

Tags: white-space, soul

I am trying to write a document template in which the necessary text would be set using `\def` at the beginning, and then used in the text. And I ran into the problem that if there are spaces in the original macro, then when using it inside `\ul` from the `soulutf8` package, the spaces do not disappear:

```
\def\text{ some text }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}
\def\textWithoutSpaces{\ignorespaces\text\unskip}
\ul\textWithoutSpaces
\end{document}
```

What I want to get: the result is equivalent to `\ul{some text}`

What I get: the result is equivalent to `\ul{ some text }`

How to fix this code so that there are no spaces at the beginning and at the end of the `\ul` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to lualatex and use the `lua-ul` package:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex 

\def\text{ some text }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}
\def\textWithoutSpaces{\ignorespaces\text\unskip}

\textWithoutSpaces

\underLine{\textWithoutSpaces}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there ways without using other engines, that is, within `pdflatex`?

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov lua-ul is much more robust than soul. Also as you are using `soulutf8` you are probably using special characters, which will be much easier to handle in an unicode aware engine like lualatex.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov Manually, you can just `\ul{some text}`. Automatically, it's (nearly) impossible to solve (unless you make a lot of assumptions such as the commands are exhaustively expandable etc.).

Comment: @user202729 And if we assume that there will be a regular text?

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov Then it's possible, but I suspect that your real use case is more complicated than that. (if it were the case why would there be spaces in the original text in the first place?) Plus, it uses some programming in TeX, so if you're not familiar with TeX programming then it will be difficult to adapt the answer to your real use case.

Comment: _why would there be spaces in the original text in the first place?_ If the text is long, then it is easier to set it like this: `\def\text{[new line]    some text[new line]}`.

Answer (score 2):

`\ul` doesn't like `\ignorespaces`.

I'd not use `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` and define a variant of `\newcommand` that does (controlled) full expansion over the replacement text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\trimspaces}{m}
 {
  \tl_trim_spaces:e { \text_expand:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\expnewcommand}{\ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand}

\newcommand\mytext{ some text }
\expnewcommand\mytexttrimmed{\trimspaces{\mytext}}

\begin{document}

\ul\mytexttrimmed

\end{document}
```

In this way, `\mytexttrimmed` is defined to `some text` without leading or trailing spaces (if there were to begin with).

[image]

With a not so recent TeX distribution, replace the preamble with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\trimspaces}{m}
 {
  \tl_trim_spaces:e { \text_expand:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { e }

\NewDocumentcommand{\expnewcommand}{\exp_args:NNe\newcommand}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Note: `\expnewcommand` doesn't have the full features of `\newcommand`, use it only for defining parameterless macros.

Comment: when making up text using `pdflatex`, it gives an error `Undefined control sequence` for `\ExpandArgs`. How to fix it?

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov By updating your TeX distribution. I added a workaround, though.